# What's the meaning of this sentence "Does anyone ever get this right?"

Tags: phrase-meaning

in a [lyric of a song by QOTSA](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/q/queens+of+the+stone+age/the+vampyre+of+time+and+memory_21061556.html) have the sentence below:

> "Does anyone ever get this right?"

Is it the same meaning of this sentence?

> "Does no one ever understand this correctly?"

Comment: Saying what song you are listening to, and providing a link to lyrics can be very helpful. The meaning of lyrics in songs can be very difficult to say correctly even with the full song.

Comment: the link to lyric http://www.lyricsfreak.com/q/queens+of+the+stone+age/the+vampyre+of+time+and+memory_21061556.html @Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Get [something] right* often means *understand [something] correctly*, but it can also mean ***do*** [something] correctly.

> [The Supremes got it right on affirmative action](http://video.foxnews.com/v/3504658286001/krauthammer-the-supremes-got-it-right-on-affirmative-action/#sp=show-clips) = The Supreme Court rendered the proper decision in the case involving affirmative action.

In another song, Keith Urban sings that he believes he has finally succeeded in establishing a sound relationship with the woman he sings to:

> All of my life I've been lookin' for someone
>   Who believes in love the way I do
>   And I know I've make my share of big mistakes
>   But girl I promise you
>   That we can make this work out baby, I know it's true
>   Can't picture myself with no one but you
>   And I think I got it right this time

The singer in your song appears to be unable to deal successfuly with love and life, and asks plaintively whether *anybody* can do so.

Answer (score -1):

Does noone ever understand this correctly?

First in a question, in simple present you must have the verb in the present tense -not understood- but understnad.

I think it depends on the content of the song, as it could mean what you wrote, so if anyone understands it correctly and as well if anyone can do things the right way.

Comment: This isn't very clear - do you mean the meaning depends on the cotext in the song?